# Scrolling Text either vertically or horizontally

Tags: text, scroll

How would I cause text to scroll either vertically or horizontally? (And be able to change the speed of the scroll). Any help to get me started would be appreciated.

Comment: A hint about what programming language you use might help.

Comment: are you talking about on a web page?

Comment: I'm sorry, this was my first question on stackoverflow and I didn't realize the tag options.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about web development and do **not** want to use the non-standards `<marquee>` element, you should implement it in JavaScript. A nice solution, a plugin for jQuery library - here: http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I thought that I posted this question in the 'Android' tag. The programming lang. I'm referring to is Android Java. Anyone know how to scroll text in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Straight out of basic HTML 1.0:

```
<div align="center">
      <font color="#FFF" size="2">
          <marquee bgcolor="#000080" direction="right" loop="20" width="75%">
              <strong>This is cool!</strong>
          </marquee>
       </font>
</div>
```

or vertical

```
<div align="center">
    <marquee bgcolor="#000080" scrollamount="2" direction="up" loop="true" width="35%">
        <center>
            <font color="#ffffff" size="+1">
                <strong> THIS IS A COOL WAY<br>
                TO MAKE YOUR TEXT<br>
                SCROLL UPWARDS<br><br>
                IT IS EASY AND FAST LOADING 
                </strong>
            </font>
        </center>
      </marquee>
</div>
```

Don't sweat the comments man.

Comment: Maybe you should hint that this is a non-standard HTML tag and that one cannot assume that this support by all browsers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: The comments are perfectly appropriate.  The question doesn't have nearly enough information to arrive at an answer without guessing.